# Working with frames in java passing sessions from one frame to another

Tags: java

How can I make sure a particular frame can't be accessed without first accessing another frame. Just like sessions in ASP.NET, you can't open an admin page without having logged in. It will redirect you to the log in page. So how can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you talking about Java applets or Java applications? If I were you, I will simply implement my own codes to check the log-in status.

Answer (score 0):

This codes shows how you can do your own implementation to check the log-in status of the user.

```
class User{
    //class attributes not shown (name, pw, id..etc)
    privateboolean loggedIn;

    public Boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return loggedIn;
    }  
}

class LoginPage extends JFrame{
   //Your implementation for log in page
}

class OtherPage extends JFrame{
   if(!user.isLoggedIn()){
        new LoginPage();   //open login page
        dispose();         //close current window
   }
}
```

Certainly, with login and password involved, there are more things you have to implement other than the codes I show you above.

But if you were to implement your own checking, this is one possibility.